# Analytics filter - hostname including directory?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I have a regex filter set up on an analytics profile to only include data from a specific subdomain:

`^subdomain\.domain\.com`

This works well. Problem is, that the admin section for this site is under a different subdomain. I don't want to include all traffic from the other subdomain in this profile, only the data for admin sections relating to this profile. For example, I want to add a filter to to the original profile to include traffic from:

`othersubdomain.domain.com/admin/edit/`

Should this still be a hostname filter? Any help with direction / regex would be greatly appreciated.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system accepts logical "or" operator `|`, then use

```
^subdomain\.domain\.com|^othersubdomain\.domain\.com/admin/edit/
```

Comment: Thanks @Ωmega. Have added it to the profile hostname filter but need to wait for analytics to update. Will give it a tick when it works :)